Ami creation from s3 bucket stored file
I have a template stored in my s3 which i transferred from different aws account. Now i want create a ami to launch an instance with same template but i am unable to convert that template or file into ami.
I tried creating iam policy to connect my instance to s3 but couldn't not move ahead
